# Divide field by field in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

`{a: 1, b: 1, ratio: null}`

how to I can update atomically `ratio` field, if `ratio = a / b` ?

Comment: @chridam tell me please, where is answer? Сan you copy the line of code here or remove duplicate flag?

Comment: See the answer -  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14423151/1388513

Comment: `db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        { "$addFields": { 
            "ratio": { "$divide": [ "$a", "$b" ] } 
        }},
        { "$out": "collection" }
    ]
)` Add checks for the `b` field to be non-zero or not null.

Comment: @chridam thanks, but is it atomically?